# Laravel orWhere with left join

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm not that good with Laravel Eloquent, so be cool pls.

I have 1 product table and 4 "target" tables (sales, novelties, liquidations and exposure).

I'm trying to get all products that have at least one of the four "targets" with this query:

```
return Product::leftjoin('sales', 'sales.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->leftjoin('liquidations', 'liquidations.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->leftjoin('noveltys', 'noveltys.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->leftjoin('exposures', 'exposures.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
        ->select('products.*', 'sales.*', 'liquidations.*', 'noveltys.*', 'exposures.*')
        ->where('noveltys.novelty_end_at', '!=', null)
        ->orwhere('sales.sale_end_at', '!=', null)
        ->orWhere('liquidations.liquidation_end_at', '!=', null)
        ->orWhere('exposures.exposure_end_at', '!=', null)
        ->get();
```

Problem is, it only return products that have the first "where" clause true. (In other word, currently, this query only return produtcs with a `not null novelty_end_at`, it doesn't return products with a `sale_end_at` and others).

How can I achieve that it also return products with a not null `sale_end_at`, `exposure_end_at` and a `liquidation_end_at` ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it's almost the same thing, execpt that I'm using `orWhereNotNull` and that I'm using `DB::table` at the start instead of `Product::leftjoin` directly.

```
 return DB::table('products')
            ->leftjoin('sales', 'sales.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->leftjoin('liquidations', 'liquidations.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->leftjoin('noveltys', 'noveltys.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->leftjoin('exposures', 'exposures.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
            ->whereNotNull('sales.sale_end_at')
            ->orwhereNotNull('noveltys.novelty_end_at')
            ->orwhereNotNull('liquidations.liquidation_end_at')
            ->orwhereNotNull('exposures.exposure_end_at')
            ->get();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use `->orWhereHas()` method. To use this function, you must define the relationship in your Sales and the four target **Model** classes. Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships

Then in your query,

```
return Product::whereHas('noveltys', function(Builder $query) {
                  // your where clause
              })
              ->orWhereHas('sales', function(Builder $query) {
                  // your where clause
              })
              ->orWhereHas('liquidations', function(Builder $query) {
                  // your where clause
              })
              ->orWhereHas('exposures', function(Builder $query) {
                  // your where clause
              })
              ->get();
```